# Oracle select a sample of records for each item in list

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table product with columns id, color, item.

```
select distinct color from product
```

Is there a way without doing a bunch of unions, to select up to 2 records for each color from the product table?

I would love to be able to do something like

```
select distinct color from product sample 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `union`s!  Just use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by color order by color) as seqnum
      from product p
     ) p
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, color, item
from   ( select id, color, item, 
                row_number() over (partition by color order by null) as rn
         from   product
       )
where rn <= 2;
```